# How do I view equipment stats in Age of Wonders: Shadow Magic?

Tags: age-of-wonders-shadow-magic

I just returned to Shadow Magic after a long absence and something has me stumped: how do I view equipment stats? I just looted a ruin and found a Hell Sword, which I've duly equipped on my hero, but I have no idea what it actually does.

I'm pretty sure there's a way do this, because I don't remember having any such issues before, but I can't remember how and there's nothing useful in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mouse over an item, the item's name and attributes are listed at the very bottom of the screen (underneath the party list).

In the image below, I have moused over my armor, and you can see it is Thunder Armor, giving defense, resistance, and lightning immunity.

[image]

Comment: I was playing it windowed in wine, and just enough of the window was cut off at the bottom to hide that status line. Oops.